# Laravel, access to different controller and method according to second parameter without redirection

Tags: php, laravel

I'll rather try to explain my issue trough a code. Just please don't tell me that i shouldn't do it like that. I simply need that to be done this way if it is possible.

Also, it would be great if it is possible to avoid simple "Redirect::to()" as a way to set controller.

Laravel's docs are horrible so i couldn't figure it out if it is possible at all.

```
Route::post('ajax/{param?}', function()
{
    // HOW TO USE DIFFERENT CONTROLLER@METHOD FOR EACH DIFFERENT PARAM

    switch($param) {
    case 'one':
        // HOW TO SET CONTROLLER UserController@param1 HERE
    break;
    case 'two':
       // HOW TO SET CONTROLLER UserController@param2 HERE
    break;

    }


});
```

Comment: use a function in your controller which will contain the switch, and then it will call the desired function respectively from there

Comment: i would do that but the case is that i want to spread ajax functions in different controllers. Each places in a controller where it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to avoid making an additional HTTP request, you can do

```
return App::make('YourController')->yourMethod($param);
```